# Relative file paths in Lua?

Tags: lua, filepath, relative-path

I'm having some trouble using relative file paths in Lua, I'm not sure what the syntax is supposed to be.

If I have something like:

```
Parent Directory: File1.lua
              |
              |-----> Folder1: script.lua
```

If I wanted to use script.lua in File.Lua how would I format the dofiles(), require ' ', and filename strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dofile` and filename strings can use `"Folder1/script.lua"`.

For `require`, use `require"Folder1.script"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I formatted the dofile as such, but I still get the error "file does not exist". Note: The scripts are running in Wireshark.

Comment: Your answer is still correct, so I'm going to accept it.

Comment: If lhf's code isn't working for you, then I suspect Wireshark is invoking your script in such a way that the script's working directory is not the same as the directory in which the script lives, in which case relative paths won't work.

Try `dofile` with an _absolute_ path to your script and see if that gets you anywhere.

Alternatively, you can add the absolute path to your script's directory to Lua's `package.path` variable:

`package.path = package.path .. ';<absolute path goes here>'`

And use `require 'Folder1.script'` as per lhf's answer.